# Ubuntu 14.04 Can't connect to internet

Tags: 14.04

I just installed 14.04 on my desktop, all went well but it won't let me get on the internet. I have looked at the simulair questions about this issue, but I still do not understand what to do. My knowledge of all this is very low. i figured it would just be simple, install ubuntu and ready to go.But I guess it's not :(

So i tried to reinstall windows, but now it wont let me anymore. I have no clue what to do now, cant install windows back and ubuntu wont let me go online, please someone help me. I hope it will not be too technical.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Ethernet but if you cannot then if you look at the top of the screen there is a little rounded triangle this is your Wi-Fi then you select your network and enter your password (If you have one) If you tried this then I don't know

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. the weird thing is when \i look in settings at connection,it says it's connected. But it won't let me open any page, or download anything from the ubuntu service center. when I go to the top to the rounded triangle, the word ethernet isn't on. I have no clue what to do now.